# Why if I find span id it catches more code?

Tags: php

I have this portion of html code:

```
<div class="clear_left"></div>
<p><span class="bold_text">Full name:</span> Francesco Filippo "Frank" Bizzoni
<br><span class="bold_text">Gender:</span> Male
<br><span class="bold_text">Height:</span> 5-7.5 (172 cm)
<br><span class="bold_text">Born:</span> <span id="necro-birth" data-birth="1875-05-07"><a href="/olympics/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=5&amp;day=7">May 7</a>, 1875</span> in <a href="/olympics/friv/birthplaces.cgi?id=10423">Lodi, Lodi, Italy</a>
<br><span class="bold_text">Died:</span> <span id="necro-death" data-death="1926-12-25">December 25, 1926</span> in Bronx, New York, United States
<br><span class="bold_text">Country:</span> <img src="http://static.spref.com/olympics/images/flags/ITA.png" alt="ITA" title="Italy" height=15 width=22>&nbsp;<a href="/olympics/countries/ITA/">Italy</a>
<br><span class="bold_text">Sport:</span> <a href="/olympics/sports/CYC/">Cycling</a>
</div>
```

I'm interested to get only data-birth (in format 1875-05-07) and also data-death (same format), place birth (Lodi, Lodi, Italy) and place death (Bronx, New York, United States).
But if I use this code:

```
foreach($html4->find("span id=") as $tag4){


                    echo $tag4 . "\n";
            }
```

where html4 contains that portion of html code above, it finds me many other span:

```
<span class="bold_text">Olympics</span>
<span class="greeting"></span>
<span class="badge ui-corner-all         colors         like_a logged_out"  onclick="return sr_login_popup();" id="login_placeholder" style="display:none;"                                    >LOGIN<span id="loginform_container"></span></span>
<span id="loginform_container"></span>
<span class="badge ui-corner-all         colors         like_a logged_in"   onclick="return sr_logout();"                                                                                      >LOGOUT</span>
<span class="badge ui-corner-all tooltip disabled_badge like_a ad_free"     onclick="document.location.href='/my/auth.cgi?do=ad_free_browsing'" tip="Surf Sports Reference Ad Free">AD FREE</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<span class=bold_text>You Are Here</span>
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop=url href="/olympics/"><span itemprop=title>OLY Home</span></a></span>
<span itemprop=title>OLY Home</span>
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop=url href="/olympics/athletes/"><span itemprop=title>Athletes</span></a></span>
<span itemprop=title>Athletes</span>
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><span class=bold_text><span itemprop=title>Frank Bizzoni</span></span></span>
<span class=bold_text><span itemprop=title>Frank Bizzoni</span></span>
<span itemprop=title>Frank Bizzoni</span>
<span class="bold_text">News:</span>
<span class="poptip" tip="We've just launched the first stage of our new Sports Reference Widget tool. By clicking the \"Embed\" tooltip just above any stats table on the site you can now get the code to add our daily updated stats to your site. See the widgets page for a description [...]"><a onclick="try { pageTracker._trackEvent('blog','click','area-yah'); } catch (err) {};"  href="http://widgets.sports-reference.com/">Sports-Reference.com Widgets - Our Stats, Your Site</a> <span class="small_text">&raquo;<a href="http://www.sports-reference.com/blog/2012/02/sports-reference-com-widgets-our-stats-your-site/" onclick="try { pageTracker._trackEvent('blog','click','area-yah'); } catch (err) {};" >post</a></span></span>
<span class="small_text">&raquo;<a href="http://www.sports-reference.com/blog/2012/02/sports-reference-com-widgets-our-stats-your-site/" onclick="try { pageTracker._trackEvent('blog','click','area-yah'); } catch (err) {};" >post</a></span>
<span class="bold_text">Full name:</span>
<span class="bold_text">Gender:</span>
<span class="bold_text">Height:</span>
<span class="bold_text">Born:</span>
<span id="necro-birth" data-birth="1875-05-07"><a href="/olympics/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=5&amp;day=7">May 7</a>, 1875</span>
<span class="bold_text">Died:</span>
<span id="necro-death" data-death="1926-12-25">December 25, 1926</span>
<span class="bold_text">Country:</span>
<span class="bold_text">Sport:</span>
```

Why this?

Comment: what class/plugin is `$html4`? what does the api/doc say about `find()` method? looks like an 'span' or 'id=' catch.

Comment: $html4 is a variable which contains entire html code of the page. I get it with a file_get_html method from the url page.

Comment: [here's the (only) manual I've found.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: I suppose you wanna filter like this: `find('span[id=necro_birth]')`

Comment: Ok, I get: <span id="necro-birth" data-birth="1875-05-07"><a href="/olympics/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=5&amp;day=7">May 7</a>, 1875</span>.  Now what if I want only 1875-05-07 ?

Comment: then read the docs how you can get that.